# extract specific numbers from randomly generated

Tags: java, arrays

New to Java. Not complete beginner but almost.

I'd like to generate 9 numbers between 9 and 18 and extract #1 and #5.
I have something for the generation but I have no idea how to extract a specific number from that.

I've got this for the generation :

```
Random rn = new Random();
int range = max - min + 1;
int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range) + min;
            System.out.print(randomNum + " ");
```

Thanks very much for your help!!!

Comment: Just run the code nine times and save only the first and fifth runs. Also I must admit I can't understand why you'd want to do that.

Comment: The numbers are random with a uniform distribution so why not simply use the first two values you receive from the sequence (`nextInt()`)?

Comment: Create an array with a length of 9, run it nine times (saving each result), then grab your two values.

Comment: put a static count variable increase count by run for each extract. add conduction for extract 1 & 5

Comment: But random means generated numbers will not be same every time you run. Then what is the use of getting #1 and #5 out only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could save all 9 generated numbers in an array and get the first and the 5th out of it!

```
Random rn = new Random();
int range = max - min + 1;
int[] rndNumbers = new int[9];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    rndNumbers[i] = rn.nextInt(range) + min;
}

rndNumbers[0]... //Do something with #1
rndNumbers[4]... //Do something with #5
```

Another possibility is to just save the first and fifth value:

```
Random rn = new Random();
int range = max - min + 1;
int first = 0, fifth = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    int randomNumber = rn.nextInt(range) + min;
    if (i == 0)                                     // first element
        first = randomNumber;
    else if (i == 4)                                // fifth element
        fifth = randomNumber;
}
```